# How to change text color of a field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report field with name 'Comp' which will contain the text 'correct' or 'not correct' according to some formula. what i want to achieve is, if text is correct i want to make it green color, otherwise red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it after some search, here is the answer

```
if{Comp} = "correct" then crGreen else crRed
```

Comment: I like that you added your own answer.  Maybe it would be helpful to tell how to get to that formula.  :)

Answer (score 1):

you can create formula in your program too:

```
FormulaFieldDefinitions definitions = MyReport.FormulaFields;
string formulaText = "IF " + MyReport.Database.Tables[1].Fields[1].Name 
+ " = correct THEN crGreen else crRed";
definitions.Add("Test", formulaText);
MyReport.Sections[1].AddFieldObject(definitions[1], 0, 0);
```